# How to filter string elements in the list which occurs in longer elements in the same list python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, filter, n-gram

I have a list which contains elements like `['love', 'hair', 'light', 'hair dryer', 'bright light', 'bright hair dryer']` and want to filter single or double word ones if they occurs in trigrams. How can I do that? At the end I should have `['love', 'bright light', 'bright hair dryer']`. In specific I need to delete hair from list because `'hair dryer'` contains it but also I have delete `'hair dryer'` because `'bright hair dryer'` has it.

Comment: So does your list become ['love', 'bright light', 'bright']? I don't understand how you're choosing to remove 'hair' and 'hair dryer', could you elaborate a little more on the choice of words to remove?

Comment: If a string is contained by a larger string I remove the smaller one. Since 'hair dryer' contains 'hair' and 'bright hair dryer' contains 'hair dryer' I remove both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution uses brute force to check each string against the remaining (slicing the array), justo for the fun of writing a one liner.

It does not removes string if the order is reversed, for example `"hair bright"` is not considered as sub of `"bright hair dryer"`.

```
[ e for i, e in enumerate(mylist) if not any([ e in s for s in mylist[:i] + mylist[i+1:] ]) ]

   #=> ['love', 'bright light', 'bright hair dryer']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the list sorted by the lengths of phrases in reverse order, and add each possible sub-phrase to a set, so that you can use the set the check if the current phrase is a sub-phrase of a previous, longer phrase:

```
output = []
seen = set()
for phrase in sorted(l, key=len, reverse=True):
    words = tuple(phrase.split())
    if words not in seen:
        output.append(phrase)
    seen.update({words[i: i + n + 1] for n in range(len(words)) for i in range(len(words) - n)})
```

so that given:

```
l = ['love', 'hair', 'light', 'hair dryer', 'bright light', 'bright hair dryer']
```

`output` becomes:

```
['bright hair dryer', 'bright light', 'love']
```